# Convert a circle face to a square?

Tags: modeling, faces, conversion

I don't know how to make that transition from a circle to a square.[image] Any ideea ?

Comment: W > LoopTools > Circle will allow you to make a circle from a square, or use W > Bridge Loops to fill the gap between a circle and a square

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are talking about more topology question, if so see the attached i have quickly put together a basic example, Its about gradually change the shape over a certain amount of edge loops with supporting loops.

[image]